# PrintDialog open file after print

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using PrintDialog and PrintDocument to generate pdf reports. The files are saved to user defined paths that is set at PrintDialog.
After the print event I want to open the file using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start.
The problem is that I do not know the user defined path.
PrintDialog.Document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName throws an exception "The given path's format is not supported.".
However the file has been created and saved correctly to the user defined path.

```
        // Allow the user to choose the page range  
        ProductionPrintDialog.AllowSomePages = true;
        // Show the help button.
        ProductionPrintDialog.ShowHelp = true;
        // Set the Document property to the PrintDocument for 
        // which the PrintPage Event has been handled. To display the
        // dialog, either this property or the PrinterSettings property 
        // must be set 
        ProductionPrintDialog.PrintToFile = true;
        ProductionPrintDialog.Document = ProductionPrintDocument;

        //ProductionPrintDialog.Document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "c:\\test.pdf";

        DialogResult result = ProductionPrintDialog.ShowDialog();

        // If the result is OK then print the document.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ProductionPrintDocument.Print();  
            if(ProductionPrintDialog.Document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName == "Microsoft Print to PDF")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProductionPrintDialog.Document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName);
            }
        }
```

How can I get the user defined path set at PrintDialog?

Comment: Can you please share your code? Otherwise it is difficult to tell what is wrong.

Comment: @KlausGütter I have added my code